# Проблема с кодировкой url на html странице в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

На странице есть ссылка с кириллицей. Если через браузер(Chrome) посмотреть код страницы, то ссылка выглядит вот так:
http://get.sweetbook.net/b/36078/I4SXM5F6MJVEmNYbUb7EBLwPKpI8eZ4t8sVT24HuWUY,/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86.mp3

А если получить страницу через urllib, то ссылка выглядит вот так:
http://get.sweetbook.net/b/36078/dcMxTA1ODDAjyUYXxstuglvFQ__MpjpMJy7-5N6ODWQ,/\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x86.mp3

Что с чем и как сделать, чтобы получать ссылку, как через браузер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы.
Но ответ нашёл методом тыка.
Во всех документациях и туториалах получение веб-страницы выглядит вот так:

```
  req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
  with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        page = response.read()
```

Но так пробелы и отступы отображаются в виде кучи \n и \t, а так же некорректно отображается кириллица.
Проблема решается вот так:

```
  req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        page = response.read().decode()
```

Comment: Просто `.decode()` неверно, если страница не использует `utf-8` кодировку. Вместо этого, нужно использовать: `.decode(page_encoding)`. Если не знаете как найти `page_encoding` кодировку веб-страницы, то задайте отдельный вопрос. See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).